# Does Cloud9 provision with t2.micro instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

Can Cloud9 be provisioned with `t2.micro` instances? It's listed as a default instance option, but every single attempt to create this has failed. If I go up to the `t2.small` instance, that runs successfully. If it's not compatible, why is it listed as a default?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "failed"? Did it display an error message? I just deployed a fully-default Cloud9 environment in the Sydney region. It deployed on a `t2.micro` instance and worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein. Added snapshots of the errors I was facing. Just went with the basic defaults. Same issue today.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Cloud9 can be provisioned on t2.micro instances.